# failed to resize svg in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Why I'm not able to resize imported svg in this case? I tried to remove the width and height value on the svg itself but doesn't work too.

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  svg {
    width: 40px;
    path {
      fill: red;
    }
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrap>
        <Logo />
      </Wrap>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-river-ertf8?file=/src/App.js:145-423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your SVG. It has a fixed height and width defined on it, but no viewBox. So change the opening tag to this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1000" width="1000" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

Then in your component, set the height and width in the styled component to scale it, e.g.

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
  svg {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    path {
      fill: red;
    }
  }
`;
```

Now the SVG will scale with the width/height properties

Comment: removing the height and width tag on the svg file itself doesn't solve the problem, you can try.

Comment: @AndreThonas that's not what I suggested at all. You need to add a `viewBox` property. You can literally copy/paste the code in my answer